# How to add images and price to an array of objects react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add images and price to an array of objects whenever enter the price or upload an image from textfield

```
const [sampleArray, setSampleArray] = useState[{image:'', price:''}]
const handleSubmit=(e)=>
{

}

result should be like this:
[{image:'apple.jpeg', price:100}, {image:'orange.jpeg', price:200}
]
```

first input field have price 100,
second input field have apple image,
third input field have price 200,
fourth input field have orange image,

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  <input type='text'  />
  < input type='file'  />
  <input type='text'/>
  < input type='file'  />
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What does your handleChange look like? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: How can we help? What you've provided unfortunately doesn't make clear any issues you're having.

Comment: please check now

Comment: on submit you want to push data in `setSampleArray` right ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't push the data in array. Try below code on submit data you will get data array!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
let sampleArray = [];

function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState([]);
  const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

  function handleBtnclick() {
    setPrice('');
    setImage('');
    sampleArray.push({
      price: price,
      image: image
    });

    console.log(sampleArray, 'obj');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type='text' value={price} onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
      <input type='file' onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
      <input type='button' value='submit' onClick={() => handleBtnclick()} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Array deceleration with image imported form assets folder

import Group609 from "../../../../assets/images/Group609.png";
import credibleandtrust from "../../../../assets/images/credibleandtrust.svg";
import support_24_7 from "../../../../assets/images/support_24_7.svg";
import refundpolicy from "../../../../assets/images/refundpolicy.svg";
 
let arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    img: Group609,
    h5a: "Instant And Fast",
    h5b: "Delivery",
    text: "We value the requirements of our customers and provide followers.",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    img: credibleandtrust,
    h5a: "Lorem Ispum",
    h5b: "Delivery",
    text: "We value the requirements of our customers and provide followers",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    img: fastdelivery,
    h5a: "Demo",
    h5b: "",
    text: "We value the requirements of our customers and provide followers.",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    img: support_24_7,
    h5a: "Demo1",
    h5b: "",
    text: "We value the requirements of our customers and provide followers.",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    img: refundpolicy,
    h5a: "Demo2",
    h5b: "",
    text: "We value the requirements of our customers and provide followers.",
  },
];

// Getting Id from children component and comparing it with array Id

const [id, getId] = useState("");
  const getFeatureSecLId = (dataVar1) => {
    getId(dataVar1);
  };
  let getFilteredRecord = arr.filter((filterVal) => {
    return filterVal.id === id;
  });

// After comparison passing the filtered value to other children component using //map method

{getFilteredRecord.map((var1) => {
              return <FeatureSectionRight dataValues={var1} />;
            })} 


// After passing values, displaying the values in the children component

<div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 core-features-content">
      <div className="row core-content core-features-003 active">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
          <div className="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
            <div className="row uk-flex">
              <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3">
                <img src={dataValues.img} />
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9">
                <h5>
                  {dataValues.h5a} <br />
                  {dataValues.h5b}
                </h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <p>{dataValues.text}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).